# Double and Float format displaying different results

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I thought that the difference between double and float were the precision of the decimals. However, I am getting strange results with using double and float and they are no where close to one another.

The first segment of code is used with the float format producing the correct results:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABSOLUTE_VALUE(number)      ( ((number) < 0) ? -(number) : (number) )

int main (void)
{
    float number, absNumber;


    printf ("What number do you want to check the absolute value for? : ");
    scanf  ("%f", &number);

    absNumber = ABSOLUTE_VALUE(number);

    printf ("The absolute value of %.2f is %.2f\n", number, absNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
What number do you want to check the absolute value for? : -3 
The absolute value of -3.00 is 3.00

The second segment of code is used with the double format producing incorrect results:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABSOLUTE_VALUE(number)      ( ((number) < 0) ? -(number) : (number) )

int main (void)
{
    double number, absNumber;


    printf ("What number do you want to check the absolute value for? : ");
    scanf  ("%d", &number);

    absNumber = ABSOLUTE_VALUE(number);

    printf ("The absolute value of %.2d is %.2d\n", number, absNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
What number do you want to check the absolute value for? : -3 
The absolute value of -03 is 2147344384

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the second example, `%d` is used for integers. (**d** isn't short for **double**, but for **decimal**)

```
scanf  ("%d", &number);
```

should be

```
scanf  ("%lf", &number);
```

The `printf` is incorrect too, as `%f`is used for `double`

```
printf ("The absolute value of %.2d is %.2d\n", number, absNumber);
```

Instead, this should be:

```
printf ("The absolute value of %.2f is %.2f\n", number, absNumber);
```

---

Notice that the format specifier for `double` is different for `scanf` and `printf`, [this C FAQ article](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfvsprintf.html) has some good explanations.

Comment: Not `%lf` (this is for `long double`) but `%f`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, in the format of `scanf`, `%f` is used for `float`, `%lf` is used for `double`. Its format is different from `printf`.

Comment: %lf is also available for print f, it is the same as %f in this case so it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Your last `printf` format string is wrong. Should be.

```
 printf ("The absolute value of %.2f is %.2f\n", number, absNumber);
```

and if you **enable all compiler warnings** (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`) you'll have a warning about that. Always enable all warnings in the compiler.

Your `scanf` are also wrong, should be `scanf("%lf", &number);` and with all warnings the compiler would have warned you.

BTW, `scanf` returns the "number of successfully matched items" and you should test its result.

You really need to carefully read the documentation of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). (In a linux terminal, you could type `man 3 printf` to get it).

Notice that arguments are converted to `double` and the conversion specifier for `double`-s is `%f` in `printf` and `%lf` in `scanf`

And you should **learn how to use a debugger** (like `gdb`).

Comment: Wrong for `scanf`, `%f` is used for `float`, `%lf` is used for `double`. Its format is different from `printf`. My answer is correct.

Comment: Is a debugger something that will be useful to me in the long run as I keep programming?

Comment: Using a debugger is in practice absolutely essential when coding, specially in C or C++ ... You really need to learn it...

Answer (score 2):

In your second program, you have used %d format specifier for double which is wrong. And that's why you are getting error. You should use %lf (long float or better called 'double') for printing it.
For other format specifier,
I think this might help you
[a link](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_30.htm)
You can also search different format specifiers on google by typing 'format specifiers'.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: but you can go to the link and can know which format specifier is for which purpose in a more tabulated and easy to read & understandable form.

Comment: @Basile telling him this is not for that etc, I personally feel may confuse him. So, I told what I think is better from my perspective

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), `"%d"` is for integers. You need `"%lf"` instead.

Ditto with the printf

Comment: So %d is used for integers? Oh darn :(
I don't know why I thought it was used for decimals as well

Comment: No, the format specifier for `double` is different for `scanf` and `printf`, see my answer. It's `%f` in `printf`.

Comment: @LinhSaysHi - I meant in the sense that the format is incorrect. Should have been more explicit